# How to properly write PHP code that displays a usernname after logging in?

Tags: php, html

I need help writing a code that displays a username after logging in! I've been following some videos to help me throughout this code so I apologize for any slip ups. I'm a beginner.

Profile.php

```
       <?php 
           require("connect.php");
           require("functions.php");
           if(logged_in())
           {
```

HTML

```
    <a href="changepassword.php">Change Password</a>
    <a href="logout.php" style="float:right; padding:10px; margin-right:40px; background-color:#eee; color:#333; text-decoration:none;">Logout</a>
    <!--This is where I'm going to add my php code to display-->
    <p> {first name} {last name} Profile</p>
    <p> {username}</p>


<?php 

    }
    else
    {
    header("location:login.php");
    exit();
    }

?>
```

functions.php

```
<?php 
    function email_exists($email, $con)
    {
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id FROM users WHERE email='$email'");

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

}

function logged_in()

{   

        if(isset($_SESSION['email']) || isset($_COOKIE['email']))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
}
```

And now my connection to the database

connect.php

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","****","database");

if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Error occured while connecting with database ".mysqli_connect_errno();
}
session_start();
```

signup.php

```
include("connect.php");
include("functions.php");

if(logged_in())
{
    header("location:profile.php");
    exit();
}

$error = "";

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $firstName = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['fname']);
    $lastName = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['lname']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
    $userid = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['userid']);
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $passwordConfirm = $_POST['passwordConfirm'];

    $image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $tmp_image = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $imageSize = $_FILES['image']['size'];

    $conditions = isset($_POST['conditions']);

    $date = date("F, d Y");


    if(strlen($firstName) < 3)
    {
        $error = "First name is too short";
    }

    else if(strlen($lastName) < 3)
    {
        $error = "Last name is too short";
    }
    else if(strlen($userid) > 8)
    {
        $error = "You need a longer username";
    }
    else if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
    {
        $error = "Please enter valid email address";
    }
    else if(email_exists($email, $con))
    {
        $error = "Someone is already registered with this email";
    }
    else if(strlen($password) < 8)
    {
        $error = "Password must be greater than 8 characters";
    }
    else if($password !== $passwordConfirm)
    {
        $error = "Password does not match";
    }
    else if($image == "")
    {
        $error = "Please upload your image";
    }
    else if($imageSize > 1048576)
    {
        $error = "Image size must be less than 1 mb";
    }           
    else if(!$conditions)
    {
        $error = "You must be agree with the terms and conditions";
    }
    else
    {   
            $password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

            $imageExt = explode(".", $image);
            $imageExtension = $imageExt[1];

            if($imageExtension == "PNG" || $imageExtension == "png" || $imageExtension == "JPG" || $imageExtension == "jpg")
            {
                $image = rand(0, 100000).rand(0, 100000).rand(0, 100000).time().".".$imageExtension;

                $insertQuery = "INSERT INTO users(firstName, lastName, userid, email, password, image) VALUES ('$firstName','$lastName','$userid','$email','$password','$image')";
                if(mysqli_query($con, $insertQuery))
                {
                    if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_image,"images/$image"))
                    {
                        $error = "You are successfully registered";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $error = "Image is not uploaded";
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $error = "File must be an image";
            }
    }

}
```

login.php

```
if(logged_in())
{
    header("location:profile.php");
    exit();
}

$error = "";

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']);
    $checkBox = isset($_POST['keep']);

    if(email_exists($email,$con))
    {
        $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT password FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
        $retrievepassword = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

        if(!password_verify($password, $retrievepassword['password']))
        {
            $error = "Password is incorrect";
        }
        else
        {
            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;

            if($checkBox == "on")
            {
                setcookie("email",$email, time()+3600);
            }

            header("location: profile.php");
        }


    }
    else
    {
        $error = "Email Does not exists";
    }




}
```

Comment: Either add all the user data you need to the session on signup (drawback: data must be updated if the user updates his/her profile), or query for the logged in user data on each page request (drawback: one more query, performance wise this shouldn't matter though). Then it's just an if to check if you have a logged in user, and if so, echo the user data (from session or from what you retrieved from the db)

Comment: Hello JimL! Thank you, but see I know what you're talking about I'm just not sure how to write that in my code. :(

Comment: If you have written the code above it should be rather simple. It's just minor modifications. If you ever consider putting this code online though I would strongly advise you to utilize mysqli and use prepared/parameterized queries. You can then remove all those "escape string" lines, and be more secure against sql injection attacks.

Comment: Alright. Thank you so much, again JimL!

Comment: Umm, I'm sorry. But whenever I go to put $_SESSION['userid'] = $userid I get an unidentified variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may "save" any information to a session so that you may retrieve it on other web pages by using the `$_SESSION` variable. For example, if you add `$_SESSION['userid'] = $_POST['userid'];` after session_start() would save the username for use in the future. Use the following tag to include the username in your HTML: `<?php echo $_SESSION['userid']`; ?>

Comment: Ahh Thank you so much, Michael!

Comment: Actually I got one more question. Where would I put this code? In connect.php?

Answer (score 0):

First of all what you need to do is to check if the user is successfully logged in with the required details which will mostly contain the username and a password.
After that, you need to store the username of the user in the session. e.g

`<?php
    // Set session variables
    $_SESSION["username"] = $username; //The username the user used to login to 
    your site
 ?>`

Anywhere you need to use the username, you can echo `<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>`

Comment: This is awesome dealwap! Thank you so much!

Comment: Actually I got one more question. Where would I put this code? In connect.php?

Comment: Put it in the file that processes your login. It should be executed only after a successful login.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a Session when the login is successful. Like

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['FirstName'] = firstName; //The firstname the user typed in
$_SESSION['LastName'] = lastName; //The lastname the user typed in
?>
```

Comment: Much appreciated, Simpson! Thank You! And to display all I need to do is echo?

Comment: Actually I got one more question. Where would I put this code? In connect.php?

Comment: You already set a session variable in your login code, this would be the appropriate place to add more data to the session.

Comment: Umm, I'm sorry. But whenever I go to put $_SESSION['userid'] = $userid I get an unidentified variable.

Comment: have u added the session within your if(isset ?

Comment: I just used (isset($_POST['id'])) and I still could not see the username I echo'd.

Comment: if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{ You can put it in like this     $_SESSION['email'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
    $_SESSION['password'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']); } echo $_SESSION['email'];

Comment: Thank you, Simpson. There's only one problem. When ever I try to log in, it disappears. Also, when I sign up, it doesn't go into the database. May you help me with that?

Comment: what disappears, and secondly, when a login is succesfull, use header:location profile.php or what page u wannt to refer to when logged in